# Attach global to Vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I attach global filters/mixins/and more to a defined Vue Instance instead of the Vue object?

**Example**

```
import Vue from 'vue.js'
import App from './app'
import demo from './mixins/demo'

Vue.mixin(demo)

const vm = new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App).$mount('#app')
})
```

How to attach this mixin to **vm** instead of the **Vue object** in the case where I have multiple instances?

> I tried **vm.mixin(demo)** but It doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not that clear but I feel what you want is to have multiple Vue root instances on the page each with it's own set of **global** mixins/directives/filters etc.

Unfortunately Vue 2 was not designed in a way to make this easy. Great read on this is [Global API](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#a-new-global-api-createapp) section of Vue3 migration guide (citations):

> Vue 2.x has a number of global APIs and configurations that globally mutate Vue’s behavior.

> While this approach is convenient, it leads to a couple of problems. Technically, Vue 2 doesn't have a concept of an "app". What we define as an app is simply a root Vue instance created via `new Vue()`. Every root instance created from the same Vue constructor **shares the same global configuration**. As a result:

> Global configuration makes it difficult to share the same copy of Vue between multiple "apps" on the same page, but with different global configurations

This is a problem mainly (but not exclusively) during the testing. To fix it, they  introduced [createLocalVue()](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/createLocalVue.html) [method](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/blob/dev/packages/shared/create-local-vue.js) in vue-test-utils, which uses [Vue.extend](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend) global API to create a "subclass" of base Vue constructor...

So I'v used the same approach to create an example below which shows 2 different Vue subclasses each with it's own set of global mixins and components. It sort of works but has it's quirks (for example take a look how components are registered - leaving out `MyVue1.extend` call breaks the code)

My take from this exercise is that it can be done with Vue 2 but it can be a bumpy road and probably best solution is to use Vue 3 where those problems were solved properly...

```js
const MyVue1 = Vue.extend()
const MyVue2 = Vue.extend()

MyVue1.mixin({
  methods: {
    mixinMethod: function() {
      return 'MyVue1'
    }
  }
})

MyVue1.component('my-component1', MyVue1.extend({
  template: '<div> Hello from my-component1: {{ mixinMethod() }} !</div>'
}))

MyVue2.mixin({
  methods: {
    mixinMethod: function() {
      return 'MyVue2'
    }
  }
})

MyVue2.component('my-component2', MyVue2.extend({
  template: '<div> Hello from my-component2: {{ mixinMethod() }} !</div>'
}))

const vm1 = new MyVue1({
  template: '<my-component1 />',
}).$mount('#app1')

const vm2 = new MyVue2({
  template: '<my-component2 />',
}).$mount('#app2')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app1"></div>
<div id="app2"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.
This is indeed what I'm looking for, but it seems that using Vue.extend() restrains the effect to the component itself and not its children, whereas the global Vue object is recursive.
I had a look at this Vue.extend method in the 2.0 doc and it looks like there are no workaround. Best solution might be to upgrade to 3.0 indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it?

```
import fooMixin from './mixins/fooMixin'
import barMixin from './mixins/barMixin'

const vm1 = new Vue({
  router,
  mixins: [fooMixin]
  render: h => h(App).$mount('#app1')
})

const vm2 = new Vue({
  router,
  mixins: [barMixin]
  render: h => h(App).$mount('#app2')
})
```

Comment: This would apply the mixin to the root but not the child elements